# Ruby add a calendar month

Tags: ruby, date

Am new to ruby, and having an issue with some date functions. I am trying to add a calendar month to a supplied date, so that "30th Apr 2002", would output "31st May 2002". Here is my code

```
 date = '30th Apr 2002'
 parseDate = Date.parse(date)

(parseDate >> 1) # This returns 2002-05-30
```

Maybe this is not how the function is supposed to work, in which case I would need to write some code to return the last day of the next month, if the supplied date is the last day of the month?

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: So what would you have to add a month to in order to get 30th May 2002? If I were asked for the date one calendar month after 30th April, I'd say 30th May...

Comment: Yeah, this is the logic i would expect, however my requirements state that a reminder email should be sent one calendar month before the due date. If the due date is 31st May, a reminder email should be sent on the 30th Aprl

Comment: So that's not *adding* a calendar month - that's *subtracting* a calendar month, which is very different.

Comment: Ok, this is where my logic may be wrong, have been calculating in the wrong direction

Comment: What does "one calendar month" mean to you? 28 days? 30 days? 31 days?

Comment: Hi cat, i think my issue was what Jon has highlighted - subtracting the calendar month has resolved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The [`>>`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3E-3E) does just increment the month and keep the same day within the month, which as Skeet noted in a comment is somewhat sensible...

But to get the behavior you want, you can just add and subtract a day in the right order to take the last day across the month boundary and back:

```
((parseDate +1) >> 1) - 1
```

For subtracting months, as it appears from comments you really want, use the same trick but the reverse month operator.

```
((parseDate +1) << 1) - 1
```

Comment: Will this just work in the edge case I provided? Or with all months? Thanks

Comment: Yes on the case you provided, as I verified in irb.  I see no reason it wouldn't work in general.

Comment: won't work for february, since the 28th or 29th + 1 won't roll it to the next month -- the rest of the months should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

with activesupport

```
parseDate = parseDate + 1.month.since(parseDate)
```

or 30 days exactly, so it it might slip a bit

```
parseDate = parseDate + (30*24*60*60)
```

Comment: Hi, I think maybe my question wasnt 100% clear. Jon Skeet has helped me, thanks for your help anyway. Thanks